# Bounded holomorphic extension to Cantor set

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, cantor-set

Let $C$ be the Cantor set and $f$ be a bounded holomorphic function on $\{|z|<2\}\setminus C$. Show that $f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $\{|z|<2\}$.

My friend gave me this problem, although I don't know much complex analysis. To show that a function can be extended to a larger domain, you show that the limits of the function at the new points exist. I don't see how to do that. I don't know how to use $f$ being bounded, although I realize it's important because otherwise the statement is false for $f=\tfrac{1}{z-2/3}$, since $\tfrac{2}{3}\in C$. This problem piqued my curiosity, and I'm interested in a solution.

Comment: $\mathcal{H}^1(C)=0$ since at each step of the construction of $C$, you have it covered by intervals of length $1/3^n$ with total length $2^n/3^n$, and then [Theorem 2.7 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02582.pdf).

Comment: This is not an answer, but I would like to point out that Exercise  10 in the chapter on Analytic Continuation in Rudin's RCA has a lot of information on this question. It also has hints for answering your question.

Comment: In the proof of Theorem 2.7, how does $f’(\infty)$ make sense? $f$ is only defined on $\Omega$.